# How to have multiple variables in Python run through the same function from a site package?

Tags: python

I'm making a terminal stock portfolio tracker in Python using the yahoo_fin package and exporting the data in a table using tabulate. My variables are individual stock tickers (in this case, PTON, CHWY, and FUBO). Is there a way to have to have a set of variables run though the same line of function code? As you'll see in my current code, I have to edit each variable within the function to have the table work. Ideally, the code would just read each ticker through the same line of code instead of individually editing each set.

This is my first post so apologies if the formatting for the code is wrong. Thank you.

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
from datetime import datetime
from tabulate import tabulate

now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')

# tape = "PTON, CHWY, FUBO"
print(time)

tkr1 = 'PTON'
tkr2 = 'CHWY'
tkr3 = 'FUBO'

# FIGURE OUT A WAY TO HAVE EACH TICKER RUN THROUGH THE PACKAGE WITHOUT HAVING TO MAKE DIFFERENT VARIABLES
# You could have like Run #1 defined as a variable, so Run1 = [], run2 = [] etc. 

#1
output1 = si.get_live_price(tkr1)
# get quote_table
quote1 = si.get_quote_table(tkr1)
# get data from quote_table:
prevclose1 = quote1.get("Previous Close")
vol1 = quote1.get("Volume")
rangeday1 = quote1.get("Day's Range")
range52_1 = quote1.get('52 Week Range')
percentchange1 = (output1/prevclose1)-1
percentage1 = "{:.2%}".format(percentchange1)
earningsdate1 = quote1.get('Earnings Date')

#2
output2 = si.get_live_price(tkr2)
# get quote_table
quote2 = si.get_quote_table(tkr2)
# get data from quote_table:
prevclose2 = quote2.get("Previous Close")
vol2 = quote2.get("Volume")
rangeday2 = quote2.get("Day's Range")
range52_2 = quote2.get('52 Week Range')
percentchange2 = (output2/prevclose2)-1
percentage2 = "{:.2%}".format(percentchange2)
earningsdate2 = quote2.get('Earnings Date')

#3
output3 = si.get_live_price(tkr3)
# get quote_table
quote3 = si.get_quote_table(tkr3)
# get data from quote_table:
prevclose3 = quote3.get("Previous Close")
vol3 = quote3.get("Volume")
rangeday3 = quote3.get("Day's Range")
range52_3 = quote3.get('52 Week Range')
percentchange3 = (output3/prevclose3)-1
percentage3 = "{:.2%}".format(percentchange3)
earningsdate3 = quote3.get('Earnings Date')


#Tabulate
data = [[tkr1, round(output1, 2), percentage1,(f'{vol1:,}'),rangeday1,range52_1,earningsdate1], 
[tkr2, round(output2, 2), percentage2,(f'{vol2:,}'),rangeday2,range52_2,earningsdate2], 
[tkr3, round(output3, 2), percentage3,(f'{vol3:,}'),rangeday3,range52_3,earningsdate3]]

print(tabulate(data, headers=["Ticker", "Price", "% Chg", "Volume", "Day Range", "52 Range", "Earnings"]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a function:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
from datetime import datetime
from tabulate import tabulate

now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')

# tape = "PTON, CHWY, FUBO"
print(time)
tkr1 = 'PTON'
tkr2 = 'CHWY'
tkr3 = 'FUBO'

def get_ticker_run(ticker_code):
    
    output = si.get_live_price(ticker_code)
    # get quote_table
    quote = si.get_quote_table(ticker_code)
    # get data from quote_table:
    prevclose = quote.get("Previous Close")
    vol = quote.get("Volume")
    rangeday = quote.get("Day's Range")
    range52 = quote.get('52 Week Range')
    percentchange = (output/prevclose)-1
    percentage = "{:.2%}".format(percentchange)
    earningsdate = quote.get('Earnings Date')

    return [ticker_code, round(output, 2), percentage,(f'{vol:,}'),rangeday,range52,earningsdate]
```

Finally, use it:

```
data = [
      get_ticker_run(tkr1), 
      get_ticker_run(tkr2), 
      get_ticker_run(tkr3)
  ]

print(tabulate(data, headers=["Ticker", "Price", "% Chg", "Volume", "Day Range", "52 Range", "Earnings"]))
```